# photo gallery using ecmascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create a Photo gallery slide show using ecmascript OR JavaScript in SharePoint 2010 site.

I created a picture library called "photo gallery" .
I don't want to use picture library slide show web part.
Please suggest a code for creating the slideshow .

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward. I have worked on something similar. I can't share the code but I will share the algorithm.

1. Add a jquery repeator template in Ascx from reference http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js
2. Create your html within the template. Example:
3. You ecma script in your webpart to get the list items from picture library as collection. Also create a container like ItemContainer = { ItemList: [] };
4. Use getEnumerator() for the collection to initiate a enumerator and iterate throught the pic library items in while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){}
5. Add items to container like ItemContainer.ItemList.push(imgUrl:oListItem.get_item("Urlfield"))
6. Append the container to jquery template created.
7. Deploy and Add this webpart in a page to see the slide show as per your design.